# Is that possible to specify the copy field source as different collection field in SOLR?

Tags: solr

I am having an issue with the partial update in SOLR. As I am having some non-stored fields in my collection the values in the non stored fields gone after the partial update. So, is that possible to use copy field to copy the original content for the non stored field from a different collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. copyFields are invoked when a document is submitted for indexing, so I'm not sure how that would semantically work either. In practice what a copyField instruction does is to duplicate the field value when the document arrives to the server and copy it into fields with other names. That assumption won't make sense if there's a different collection involved - does it get invoked when documents are submitted for the other collection? (if that's the case - what with the other fields local to the actual collection).

Set the fields to stored if you want to use partial updates with fields that can't support [in place updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates) (which have very peculiar requirements, such as being non-stored, non-indexed, single valued and has numeric docValues).

Comment: I do not have this requirement 

does it get invoked when documents are submitted for the other collection?

as the data in the other collection is a constant large data. So, I do not want that as stored in my working collection. As it will affect the performance.